# Azure IoT Edge Hub Python SDK is not fault tolerant?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

The way Azure IoT Edge Python SDK forces you to handle messages does not look fault tolerant.

```
while True:
    input_message = await module_client.receive_message_on_input("input1")
    # do some work here
    # fail <<<<
    # do some work here
```

If it fails in the middle, the message will not be "resend" you again when the IoT Edge Module is fixed.

Am I right?

.NET SDK forces you to use different way, you are not responsible for picking up messages from the "queue", instead you define a callback and register it to be called on new message arrived and it expects the callback to return status message like Completed (if the message has been processed successfully). So if it fails in the middle the callback will receive it again. So it is fault tolerant and things like exceptions, device restarts are covered by this behavior.

Comment: I suggest you ask here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues

Comment: @Alex did you check [this wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/wiki/callbacks)? Like described there "Significant parts of our stack use callbacks, a pattern which is not well defined or standardized for use with Python."